# GyroListener created in onCreate() is null in onResume()

Tags: android, onresume, gyroscope

I create a GyroListener in `onCreate()` and use it in `onResume()`. Sometimes I get a NullPointerException in `onResume()`, but I don't understand how that can be, because `onCreate()` is always called be `onResume()`. This happens only in Android versions from 2.2 to 3.2.1, most users have Android 4+, and I don't have a single report of this error from their devices.

This is my code (the NullPointerException is thrown in the last line of `onResume()`):

```java
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_lock_screen);

    sensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
    sensors = sensorManager.getSensorList(Sensor.TYPE_GYROSCOPE);
    gyroListener = new GyroListener();
    gyroListener.setOnGyroEventListener(new OnGyroEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTimeReset() {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Reseted the time",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    sensorManager.unregisterListener(gyroListener);
    super.onPause();
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    for (final Sensor sensor : sensors) {
        sensorManager.registerListener(gyroListener, sensor,
                SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST);
    }
    gyroListener.resetStatus();
}
```

And this is the exception:

java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {mypackage/mypackage.activity.MyActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2124)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2139)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1672)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:935)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3691)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:912)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:670)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at mypackage.activity.MyActivity.onResume(MyActivity.java:373)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1153)
at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:3874)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2114)
... 12 more

Comment: try to do this line gyroListener = new GyroListener(); before super() call

Comment: I can try, but why do you think this would help?

Comment: Please post the exception or indicate which _object_ causes the NPE.

Comment: ...there may be a problem with your Activity life cycle callbacks. You need to call super() in all of them!

Comment: This code should throw an exception in `onPause()` and `onResume()` because you've not called `super.onXXXX()`

Comment: Sorry, I removed some unrelated code and accidently removed the super calls. I fixed it in the question.

Comment: @ClassStacker I added the exception.

Comment: In onPause, the super call should still be the first action. But anyway. Which _object_: causes the Null Pointer Exception?

Comment: It's the gyroListener.

Comment: Thanks, and which line is line 373?

Comment: gyroListener.resetStatus();

Comment: Umm okay. 1) Is there still code you haven't shown? 2) Did you try to debug, and if so, which insights did you get?

Comment: There is no more code referencing the gyroListener object. The bug does not appear on my test devices, I only see it in bug reports, so debugging did not help.

Comment: @ArthurDent At least I can't look into the GyroListener; and I tend to think that I would reset a listener's state _first_ and only _then_ re-register it, instead of the other way round? Also, I wonder whether there may be any reason the list of available sensors could somehow change  such that you would want to get the list of sensors dynamically in `onResume()`. And do you need to use `getApplicationContext()` for the Toast?